# « On va même pouvoir y manger dedans » : qu'ajoute l'emploi du pronom « y » dans cette phrase ou ce discours ?

Tags: oral, connotation, y, stylistique

Dans une [séquence](https://youtu.be/89CAY3gTWCo) de film on entend un enfant dire :

> Le château fort qu'on va faire, là, les murs vont être large « comme
> ça »,
>  Il va être plus gros que ma maison, plus haut que les
> arbres,
>  Il va, il va être super impressionnant, il va n'en avoir juste
> « un » château fort comme ça,
>  Avec des tours, des créneaux, plein de
> décorations, des portes, des fenêtres,
>  Toutes des affaires secrètes,
> on va même pouvoir **y** manger dedans,
>  Il va avoir tout qu'est-ce
> qu'on pourra mettre,
>  Il va être vraiment super beau, comme tous
> les châteaux du Moyen Âge,
>  Super super beau.
>
> [ François « Les Lunettes » ds. la [*Guerre des tuques*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Guerre_des_tuques) (Mélançon,
> 1984) ]

Qu'est-ce qu'ajoute grammaticalement, syntaxiquement, stylistiquement, thématiquement, en connotations ou registre ou autrement dans la phrase, dans le discours du locuteur, l'emploi du pronom [*y*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y/1) (*pouvoir **y** manger dedans*) ?

Answer (score 1):

L'emploi du "y" permet d'insister sur le lieu, dans ton exemple on insiste sur le fait de manger dans le château. Après dans les faits je l'utilise naturellement et ne me pose même pas la question, un peu comme le "t" de "y a-t-il". Et dans ce cas là le "y" renvoie à nouveau à la notion de lieu.

Answer (score 1):

"pouvoir manger dedans" suffirait, mais *y* ajoute au style enfantin - c'est redondant, familier sans être vulgaire, maladroit, comme "super super beau", "il va, il va juste". La beauté du texte est justement dans cette maladresse et cette familiarité enthousiaste qui ne tombe jamais dans la vulgarité.

Answer (score 0):

Tout d'abord j'ai remarqué que le mot *château* apparaît à toutes les deux lignes, et le pronom préserve cette symétrie, cette insistance et l'omniprésence du terme. Ailleurs on a abordé le style et le registre. Ma perception bien personnelle du pronom de prime abord est que son emploi est plutôt prestigieux dans cette phrase-là. Oui, c'est un enfant mais en fait connaissant bien le film il s'agit d'un champion du dessin technique et l'image du jeune prodige studieux aux lunettes rondes est accentuée à mon avis par l'association au vietnamien (le personnage parle à son frère dans cette langue).

Le pronom n'est certainement pas requis pour que la phrase fonctionne, mais il permet d'évoquer non seulement le lieu, mais en effet l'*intérieur* de celui-ci dans un syntagme (*dans le château*), et peut aussi avoir pour antécédent un adverbe de lieu comme [*là*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A0#Adverbe_1) (normalement exprimé auparavant), ou même une préposition qui n'est pas exprimée (inspiré d'une lecture sommaire du *LBU* § 677, 678). La phrase qui précède débute par *avec* (les aménagements extérieurs du château) et celle qui nous occupe dispose des « affaires secrètes » etc., on décrit essentiellement l'intérieur et ce qu'on peut y faire, incluant y manger. On a déjà l'adverbe *dedans* ([correspondant](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dedans/22529) à la préposition *dans* devant un nom) avec le verbe *manger*, l'accent est encore mis sur l'intérieur du *château*. Et cette idée colle bien à la phrase qui suit aussi (*Il va avoir tout qu'est-ce qu'on pourra mettre*). Le pronom est certainement à la croisée de différents emplois : à mon avis ils désignent tous l'*intérieur d'un lieu* dont on parle.